# Iterating over an enum without its static functions in the namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, namespaces

In Typescript 2.4+ you can have an enum type and namespace declared under same name. In namespace you can write static functions.

```
export enum Foo {
 ...
}

export namespace Foo {
 export const getAllEnumTypes = (): Foo[] => {
   return Object.keys(Foo)
      .map((key) => Foo[key]));
};
```

So the above code statement returns all the members of Foo enum but also the `getAllEnumTypes()` function as a member as well. How do we prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you sure "getAllEnumTypes" should be named a "const"? Please clarify more.

Comment: yes and that being a const is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all functions using the `typeof` operator:

```js
return Object.keys(Foo)
      .map((key) => Foo[key])
      .filter((value) => typeof value !== 'function'));
```